# I cant get my project working on Tomcat in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, jsf, tomcat7, netbeans-12

I tring to deploy a application on my localhost, and even though i can find any significative error message, and also seems like is evrithing is alright with the Deployment when try in my Localhost, the page does not appear

i seted up the maven and the tomcat on 8084 port as its seted on my tomcat propeties, still i cant get it worked

here are the project running in tomcat Log;

Scanning for projects...

```
-` br.com.agapesistemas:AgPortalNew >------------------
- Building AgPortalNew 11.23
- war ]---------------------------------
- The POM for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js2 is missing, no dependency information available
- The POM for org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3 is missing, no dependency information available
- The POM for org.primefaces.sentinel:primefaces-sentinel:jar:2.1.2 is missing, no dependency information available
- 
- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ AgPortalNew ---
- Deleting C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\target
- 
- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy (default)  AgPortalNew ---
- 
- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ AgPortalNew ---
- Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 0 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ AgPortalNew ---
Compiling 570 source files to C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\target\classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ AgPortalNew ---
Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ AgPortalNew ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ AgPortalNew ---
No tests to run.

--- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ AgPortalNew ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [AgPortalNew] in [C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\target\AgPortalNew-11.23]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [19123 msecs]
Building war: C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\target\AgPortalNew-11.23.war
Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')

--- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ AgPortalNew ---
Installing C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\target\AgPortalNew-11.23.war to C:\Users\Agape\.m2\repository\br\com\agapesistemas\AgPortalNew\11.23\AgPortalNew-11.23.war
Installing C:\Agape\AgSistemas\branches\Sprint 6 - Desenv\AgPortal\Fontes\Aplicacao\Maven\AgPortalNew\pom.xml to C:\Users\Agape\.m2\repository\br\com\agapesistemas\AgPortalNew\11.23\AgPortalNew-11.23.pom
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`

Total time:  01:55 min
Finished at: 2023-04-28T14:35:32-03:00
---------------------------------------------`

i could not see anything that could be reason behind the issue an also i am not finding any error log either
`
thats the link that i am trying to access

http://localhost:8084/AgPortalNew
[that image shows my Web Applications folder completely empty without my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jqz0.png)

Comment: How do you deploy your war?

Comment: didn't. much, beyond, import the maven project, ande the tomcat 7, i also changed some data in context of the tomcat to use my local server, and of course i configuered the maven  settings on java for use my current version  but just that

Comment: In eclipse you have to add the war to your server, so I suppose NetBeans could have a similar behavior.